# How did Neville react to Bellatrix going free?

Tags: harry-potter

A consistent pattern that I see in fan fiction is that, upon Bellatrix going free, Neville swears that he will kill her when he graduates and starts training very very hard. For whatever reason, I remember no such thing happening in canon. Did the books - and nothing else, I'm not interested in the movies or wider canon - show his reaction to her freedom? If so, what was it? Feel free to just quote straight from the text.

Comment: I'm sure he was delighted with the news

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Suffice to say he was not pleased. It spurs him to [redouble his efforts](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TookALevelInBadass) at mastering offensive and defensive magic.

> Harry was pleased to see that all of them, even Zacharias Smith, had
> been spurred on to work harder than ever by the news that ten more
> Death Eaters were now on the loose, but in nobody was this improvement
> more pronounced than in Neville. **The news of his parents’ attackers’
> escape had wrought a strange and even slightly alarming change in him.
> He had not once mentioned his meeting with Harry, Ron and Hermione on
> the closed ward in St Mungo’s and, taking their lead from him, they
> had kept quiet about it too. Nor had he said anything on the subject
> of Bellatrix and her fellow torturers’ escape. In fact, Neville barely
> spoke during the DA meetings any more, but worked relentlessly on
> every new jinx and counter-curse Harry taught them, his plump face
> screwed up in concentration, apparently indifferent to injuries or
> accidents and working harder than anyone else in the room.** He was
> improving so fast it was quite unnerving and when Harry taught them
> the Shield Charm – a means of deflecting minor jinxes so that they
> rebounded upon the attacker – only Hermione mastered the charm faster
> than Neville.
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix: CHAPTER TWENTY-FIVE - The Beetle at Bay</sup></sub>

Comment: That's all that I needed, so you've got the tick. But just to be sure, do you know of anything else? Or is there only this extract?

Comment: @J.Mini - We don't really see him for a fair while after that. The next major scene with him in is the Patronus class and he's just getting on with business.